# What is the size limit for a Query/View table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view

I am using MySQL and currently have 3 tables in a database. I created a view table with relationships between the 3 tables. The view table should be about 200 000 rows of data because i also tested the same query in Access and it works fine, but unfortunately i am not allowed to use Access.

When i build the view in MySQL i get a message that says the view was build successfully. But when i try to actually view the data, it gives me something like, MySQL ran out of memory. I am not sure what i can do differently to avoid this message. Can someone please give some advice?

Comment: *I am using MySQL and currently have 3 tables in a database ...  But when i try to actually view the data ... MySQL ran out of memory* Yeah, three tables is three tables too many for Fisher Price My First SQL Server. Have you tried a real RDBMS?

Comment: Show us the query that you are using. I wouldn't be surprised if you missed a join condition and the query generates the cartesian product between the three tables.

Comment: There just isn't enough information here to give any kind of authoritative answer but under normal circumstances 200k rows is a breeze for MySQL

Comment: @ta.speot.is: funny, but I've used MySQL for far larger databases and it does just fine. It has problems, but having more than three tables is not one of them. My guess is that there is a hidden cartesian join somewhere, or there's a bug with views (which I've been told to avoid with MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Quick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-memory.html) option for running your query.

> Do not cache each query result, print each row as it is received. This
>   may slow down the server if the output is suspended. With this option,
>   mysql does not use the history file.