# How does SQL (eg MySQL) construct multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

If we have complex query, can sorting *the where clauses* speed up the process?

Does it have any performance difference if we sort the clauses from the possibly smaller returns to larger?

Eg:

- from 1.000 of people.
- 700 are female,
- which 300 of them are graduated
- which 50 of them are also musicians.

## 1

```
WHERE gender = 'female'
AND education = 'college'
AND hobby = 'music'
```

Or better to be this?

## 2

```
WHERE hobby = 'music'
AND education = 'college'
AND gender = 'female'
```

Comment: MySQL uses its query planner to evaluate the `WHERE` clause and generates an efficient plan, discards it, [then runs out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670154/what-is-the-size-limit-for-a-query-view-table-in-mysql).

Comment: @MitchWheat done. anyway, your website has plenty of SQL info. Good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the order of clauses in the `WHERE` does not matter.

That's what the query optimiser does using column statistics.

- [Controlling the Query Optimizer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/controlling-optimizer.html)
- [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics#3402)
- [Optimization Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-overview.html)

  - [Optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

The most parts that you can provide in a WHERE clause, matching from first to last parts of an composited index, the best performance that you will have. (in general you can write in any order, but without any missing on the begining part)

Example:
Given this index  `lastname, firstname, age`, and a big table, this is a list of best to worst perfomance querys:

```
where lastname = 'gonzalez' and firstname='juan' and age=70
where lastname = 'gonzalez'
where age = 70
```

As mentioned above, the writing order is in general irrelevant as query optimizers can manage it anyway to match any index.

So, the important part is to build good indexes: Tipicaly a primary key over an integer, and some others (comosited or not) over fields matching request like in your question.  Just a last word: too much indexes are paid in space and inserts performance.

Comment: @MitchWheat, in fact the title do not mach the question. I focused on "performance difference"

Comment: @LuisSiquot I thought the order had something to do with the performance. So I believe I was expecting the answer to the title, with its goal described in the question? But I hear you though. The point is to gain better performance. Gotta read more.

Comment: well, I will edit my anwser in response to "best way to build where clause"